# How to generate new txt file with a timestamp in groovy and SoapUI?

Tags: java, jenkins, soap, groovy, soapui

I am trying to write a groovy script to generate custom logs in SOAP UI. I want the logs to be in a certain format for post-analysis that's why I don't want to rely on internal logs if present in SOAPUI.

Everytime I run a new test suite, I want to log some custom logs to a new text file. How can I achieve this in groovy?

I also want to call the test suites from a CI like jenkins and automate it to run after every 1 hour. How can I run the test suites in Jenkins? Should I write a batch file or is is there any other way present in SOAPUI?

Answer (score 1):

you can setup custom log file with specific format in the `SOAPUI/bin/soapui-log4j.xml` 
and define there a filter what should appear in it

look for different log4j config examples over the [internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=configure+log4j+xml)

so in groovy you can continue just calling `log.info(...)`

you can run your tests from command line using [`SOAPUI/bin/testrunner`](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html) tool

Comment: But is it possible in log4j to generate a new file every time with a new timestamp?

Comment: it could generate new file each hour or each minute. not really clear what does it mean `each time`... you wand to put each new message into a separate log file?

Comment: I have this doubt if it appends logs to same output file every time or a new file is created on each test run? I want seaprate files for each run like log12-02-17-08-08-08.txt and so on..

Comment: To create new file with timestamp I use something like this:   `def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss")   new File(sdf.format( new Date() )` Then using `.write(text, "UTF-8")` or append. Also test suite has Setup Script that runs at the beginning of it, that will be executed every test suite run.